# SQL Date Convert into Japan style YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, fullcalendar

When using CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),datetime,111) in my SQL query and outputting to php I get the date back in the following format.

```
2015\/08\/03
```

Is there a reason why there are the additional slashes?

My php code:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, custcode, title, description, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),datetime,111) as 'date', status
              FROM dbo.calls";

    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

    // Initializes a container array for all of the calendar events
    $jsonArray = array();

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {

        // Stores each database record to an array
        $buildjson = array('title' => $row['custcode'], 'start' => $row['date'], 'allday' => false);

        // Adds each array into the container array
        array_push($jsonArray, $buildjson);
    }

    // Output the json formatted data so that the jQuery call can read it
    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

thanks

Comment: the problem is in PHP code, provided code does not show the issue area, can you please update your question with the php code as well

Comment: @M.Ali just added the php script minus the $conn etc

Comment: @maraca oh jees.. could you explain in more detail or show in my code what I should do to change?

Comment: @maraca ive got a php page which calls the fullcalendar js file which within the function calls a JSON array which is the php script above.. when outputting just the php script directly I get..

[{"title":"test1","start":"2015\/08\/03","allday":false},{"title":"test2","start":"2015\/08\/04","allday":false}]

So the scripts working, however the receiver needs the date in the following format YYYY/MM/DD but for some reason my code is adding the additional \

Answer (score 0):

I just verified that `json_encode` does escape `/` in Strings so that it becomes `\/`. It would still be valid JSON without escaping them, but php does it anyway.

You should use a JSON parser (e.g. jQuery [`$.parseJSON(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)) to get an object from it or you can just replace `\/` by `/`.

Or see here how to [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript/4935684#4935684)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61539978d1c847ffbd56c4e56be9b21e254f88fb